# How to pass an object between fragments which are in actionbar navigation mode?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

In my app there are two fragments (MenuFragment, BasketFragment) and they are located in actionbar tab in navigation mode.

In MenuFragment i hold objects of Product class (Parcelable) in ArrayList in a listview. What i want to do is to carry product to BasketFragment in runtime when i click the item.

I have tried to do that with callback interface and bundle approaches so far and i have always faced with NullPointerException.

Please help me with that. If you would give code example, will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using a callback interface is the right way to do this. Without seeing the stack trace for the NullPointerException you were getting I'm going to assume it was because the callback wasn't correctly set. I think if you do it in `onAttach()` it should work correctly:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        mCallback = (BasketCallback)activity;
    }catch(ClassCastException ex){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.getLocalClassName() + " must implement BasketCallback");
    }
}
```

Then, you can call your callback method from your fragment, and have the activity pass the object on to the second fragment using `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.basket_fragment);`

Comment: Here is my code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192871/having-trouble-passing-object-between-fragments. Could you tell me where i make mistake?